# How to draw a vertical line graph on WPF?

Tags: wpf, linechart

I am learning to draw a line graph inside my WPF. i found a tutorial of a horizontal line graph at this side " http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/line-chart-in-wpf/ " and i manage to do it. But my question is how to draw a vertical graph?

I taking the example of the graph from the website i provided, if **transform** the graph to the **vertical graph**. The **X-axis** will be the **int(on the top)** and the **Y-axis** will be the **Date(at the left hand side)**. Anyone can help me out?

The graph i want should be like this:
 http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/202/capturegfj.jpg/

p/s : sorry, i couldn't upload an image due to low reputation point.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft provided chart controls:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.aspx

The `SeriesChartType.Line` is your chart type I guess.

Here is a sample on MSDN. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh297122%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: thanks for the information....i will go through that. But do you have any example or sample? Thanks again

Comment: That's a link to a WinForms control. Not helpful for WPF.